# Loading Test Data with BCrypt

Tags: java, authentication, junit, playframework, bcrypt

I'm using BCrypt to encrypt passwords, and I have a model that I'm trying to write tests for. I have made a YAML file with some basic test data in it, but I can't seem to get the code right.

My `Account` model:

```
package models;

import javax.persistence.*;
import org.mindrot.jbcrypt.BCrypt;
import play.data.validation.Constraints.Required;
import play.db.ebean.Model;
import play.db.ebean.Model.Finder;

@Entity
public class Account extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;
    public String email;
    public String username;
    public String passwordhash;

    public Account(String email, String username, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.username = username;
        this.passwordhash = BCrypt.hashpw(password, BCrypt.gensalt()); 
    }

    public static Finder<Long, Account> find = new Finder<Long, Account>(Long.class, Account.class);

    public static Account create(
            String username, String email, String password, 
            String confirmPassword
    ) {
        Account account = new Account(username, email, password);
        account.save();
        return account;
    }

    public static Account authenticate (String username, String password) {
        Account account = Account.find.where().eq("username", username).findUnique();
        if (account != null && BCrypt.checkpw(password, account.passwordhash)) {
            return account;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

My Model Test:

```
package ModelTests;

import models.*;
import org.junit.*;
import com.avaje.ebean.Ebean;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import play.libs.Yaml;
import play.test.WithApplication;
import static play.test.Helpers.*;

import java.util.List;

public class AccountTest extends WithApplication {

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        start(fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase()));
        Ebean.save((List) Yaml.load("test-data.yml"));
    }

    @Test
    public void authentication() {
        assertNotNull(Account.authenticate("palug", "Oxford4EVA"));
        assertNotNull(Account.authenticate("isthatastrawhat", "Supernatural"));
        assertNull(Account.authenticate("MelvIsntNormal", "meaplesss"));
        assertNull(Account.authenticate("SomeStupidHacker", "dogewow"));
    }

}
```

And my test data YAML:

```
# Accounts

- &melvin !!models.Account
    email: mxtcapps@maxtrace.co.uk
    username: MelvIsntNormal
    password: HashedPassword

- &emma !!models.Account
    email: isthatastrawhat@maxtrace.co.uk
    username: isthatastrawhat
    password: Supernatural

- &paul !!models.Account
    email: palug@maxtrace.co.uk
    username: palug
    password: Oxford4EVA
```

When I run the test, I get this error:

```
[error] Test ModelTests.AccountTest.authentication failed: org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.ConstructorException: null; Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:models.Account; exception=Cannot create property=password for JavaBean=models.Account@1c8d2d9; Unable to find property 'password' on class: models.Account;  in 'reader', line 3, column 3:
[error]     - &melvin !!models.Account
[error]       ^
[error]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructYamlObject.construct(Constructor.java:333)
[error]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructObject(BaseConstructor.java:182)
[error]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructSequenceStep2(BaseConstructor.java:276)
[error]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructSequence(BaseConstructor.java:247)
[error]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.SafeConstructor$ConstructYamlSeq.construct(SafeConstructor.java:442)
[error]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructObject(BaseConstructor.java:182)
[error]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructDocument(BaseConstructor.java:141)
[error]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.getSingleData(BaseConstructor.java:127)
[error]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadFromReader(Yaml.java:481)
[error]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.load(Yaml.java:412)
[error]     at play.libs.Yaml.load(Yaml.java:31)
[error]     at play.libs.Yaml.load(Yaml.java:18)
[error]     at ModelTests.AccountTest.setUp(AccountTest.java:18)
[error]     ...
[error] Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: Cannot create property=password for JavaBean=models.Account@1c8d2d9; Unable to find property 'password' on class: models.Account
[error]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.constructJavaBean2ndStep(Constructor.java:299)
[error]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.construct(Constructor.java:189)
[error]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructYamlObject.construct(Constructor.java:331)
[error]     ... 48 more
[error] Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: Unable to find property 'password' on class: models.Account
[error]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.introspector.PropertyUtils.getProperty(PropertyUtils.java:132)
[error]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.introspector.PropertyUtils.getProperty(PropertyUtils.java:121)
[error]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.getProperty(Constructor.java:308)
[error]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.constructJavaBean2ndStep(Constructor.java:240)
[error]     ... 50 more
[info] ModelTests.AccountTest
[info] x authentication
[info] 
[info] 
[info] Total for test ModelTests.AccountTest
[info] Finished in 0.039 seconds
[info] 1 tests, 1 failures, 0 errors
[error] Failed: Total 1, Failed 1, Errors 0, Passed 0
[error] Failed tests:
[error]     ModelTests.AccountTest
[error] (test:test) sbt.TestsFailedException: Tests unsuccessful
[error] Total time: 26 s, completed 01-Feb-2014 07:59:02
```

I understand the error is caused by the fact the the password field does not exist. However, I'm not quite sure how to go about getting the tests to invoke the Account method so the passwords would be encrypted. Can anyone help with this?

**QUESTION ANSWER (Thanks @Joe)**

I had to add a setter method for the password field:

```
public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.passwordhash = BCrypt.hashpw(password, BCrypt.gensalt());
}
```

My `Account` model now looks like this:
package models;

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import org.mindrot.jbcrypt.BCrypt;
import play.data.validation.Constraints.Required;
import play.db.ebean.Model;
import play.db.ebean.Model.Finder;

@Entity
public class Account extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;
    public String email;
    public String username;
    public String passwordhash;

    public Account(String email, String username, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.username = username;
        this.passwordhash = BCrypt.hashpw(password, BCrypt.gensalt()); 
    }

    public static Finder<Long, Account> find = new Finder<Long, Account>(Long.class, Account.class);

    public static Account create(
            String username, String email, String password, 
            String confirmPassword
    ) {
        Account account = new Account(username, email, password);
        account.save();
        return account;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.passwordhash = BCrypt.hashpw(password, BCrypt.gensalt());
    }

    public static Account authenticate (String username, String password) {
        Account account = Account.find.where().eq("username", username).findUnique();
        if (account != null && BCrypt.checkpw(password, account.passwordhash)) {
            return account;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that your `models.Account` class does not have a `password` property. SnakeYAML is looking for [either a public field called `password` or a JavaBeans setter method called `setPassword`](http://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#JavaBeans):

> By default standard JavaBean properties and public fields are included.

It is finding neither:

```
[error] Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: Unable to find property 'password' on class: models.Account
```

Instead, it has a `passwordHash` field. This suggests two possibilities:

1. Define `passwordHash` in your test data.
2. Define a `setPassword(String)` method on `models.Account` that will hash the password and store it in `passwordHash`.

A test should do one thing, so I'd suggest the first. You're testing authentication against a known password. Defining the hash as part of your test means you can see the hash of the known password in your test data, and avoid tests that pass in the face of bugs where (say) the `hashpw` method always returns the empty string.

Comment: To implement the second one (for a different test) would that just be creating a setter method for `passwordhash`?

Comment: It would be a `setPassword` method that then hashes the given password and stores it in `passwordHash`.

Comment: But in the case of this test, how can I pass the password to that method without rewriting my YAML?

Comment: Your YAML defines a `password` property. SnakeYAML tries to apply it by finding a setter called `setPassword`, which is what you would write.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, i'll try that when I get to my laptop